# Loop for in a .mousemove function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My problem is here :

```
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    for(i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        var tt = document.getElementById("tooltip"+i);
        document.getElementById("help"+i).onmousemove=function(event){
            if(tooltip == 1){
                $(tt).css({left:e.pageX+5, top:e.pageY+5});
                tt.style.visibility= "visible";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("help"+i).onmouseout=function(event){
            tt.style.visibility= "hidden";
        }
    }
});
```

With this code, the `<div id="tooltip"+i>` is showing right next to the mouse, but it's always the last "tooltip"+i, in this case tooltip6 which is showing.

I managed that to work by simply removing the loop for, and writing 6 times that next, each with a different i :

```
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
    var i = 1;
    var tt = document.getElementById("tooltip"+i);
    document.getElementById(i).onmousemove=function(){
        if(tooltip == 1){
            $(tt).css({left:e.pageX+5, top:e.pageY+5});
            tt.style.visibility= "visible";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(i).onmouseout=function(){
        tt.style.visibility= "hidden";
    }
});
```

In this case, it does what i want. It shows the tooltip1, when the mouse is over the `<div id=help1>`, and (e.g.) tooltip4 over the `<div id=help4>` if i use `var i = 4`.

I can obviously just write more and more like that as i add more tooltips, but i really don't understand why the adding of the loop is not working here.

My HTML code with the tooltips :

```
        <span id=tooltip1>Health points of the rock. Each time it gets to 0, you get some stone</span>
        <span id=tooltip2>Deeper you go, harder it is.</span>
        <span id=tooltip3>Power of the Pickaxe.</span>
        <span id=tooltip4>Go To the Village.</span>
        <span id=tooltip5>Go To the Blacksmith.</span>
        <span id=tooltip6>You can sell stone in the village.</span>
```

And HTML code with some of the help :

```
                <div class=liststat id=help1>HP : <span id=hp>0</span></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class=liststat id=help2>Deep Level : <span id=lvlrock>0</span>m</div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class=liststat id=help3>Pick Power : <span id=pickpower>0</span></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class=liststat id=help6>Stone : <span id=nstone>0</span></div>
```

Comment: I have trouble parsing your problem. What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: When i use my first code, with the loop for, the `<div id=tooltip6>` is showing when my mouse is over any of the `<div id=help+i>`,instead of `<div id=tooltip1>` over the `<div id=help1>` and `<div id=tooltip2>` over the `<div id=help2>`...

Comment: Right, can you edit your question to include the relevant HTML then?

Comment: Do you realize that every time you move your mouse you are re-assigning (in `DOM0` event listener-style) a `mousemove` listener on each of your tooltip elements? How has your script not crashed your page yet? What is your actual desired behaviour? This code is way out in left field.

Comment: I dont know, maybe i've got a good pc, im not that good in javascript yet

Comment: Unrelated sidenote, html attributes have to be in quotes if you're not writing some weird HTML3

Comment: My Desire : each tooltip(i) shows on the right help(i). I don't know why with this loop for, it always shows the last tooltip (in this case tooltip6) on every   `<div id=help(i)>

Comment: Not related, but your code is inefficient. You add listeners inside the document mousemove event, which will very easily create thousands of listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after reading the comment, i edited my code to make it simpler, and not adding any other listener, to not crash the script :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
if(tooltip == 1){
    var i = e.target.id;
    var tt = document.getElementById("tooltip"+i);
    tt.style.visibility = "visible";
    $(tt).css({left:e.pageX+5, top:e.pageY+5});
    document.getElementById(i).onmouseout=function(){
        tt.style.visibility= "hidden";
    }
}
```

});